# T-SQL - get data based on two columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to create the following output from below image:

[image: sample]

The input data is from a view (`Select * from test`). The goal is to get all data where the `progress` column contains the text `tbd` and the `counter` number is 1.

Can this be solved with case when statement?

Since sqlfiddle is not working here's the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Counter] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(200) NULL,
    [Progress] nvarchar(200) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO test
VALUES (1, 1, 'userA', 'tbd'),
       (1, 2, 'userB', 'done'),
       (1, 3, 'userC', 'tbd'),
       (2, 1, 'userB', 'done'),
       (2, 5, 'userA', 'tbd'),
       (3, 1, 'userD', 'tbd'),
       (3, 2, 'userA', 'done'),
       (3, 7, 'userC', 'tbd'),
       (3, 11, 'userB', 'tbd')
```

I couldn't get it to work.

Hope you can help me out.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Exists` clause you can achieve your desired result.

**Query**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM test t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test
            WHERE t.ID = ID
            AND progress = 'tbd'
            AND counter = 1)
```

**Result**

```
ID  Counter  Name    Progress
-----------------------------
1      1     userA   tbd
1      2     userB   done
1      3     userC   tbd
3      1     userD   tbd
3      2     userA   done
3      7     userC   tbd
3      11    userB   tbd
```

And another **alternative solution** is simple `SELF JOIN` like this-

**Query**

```
SELECT
    le.ID, le.Counter, le.Name, le.Progress
    FROM test le
INNER JOIN test re ON le.ID = re.ID
WHERE re.progress = 'tbd'
    AND re.counter = 1
```

Above query returns the same result.

Comment: @Vland: Simple `WHERE` only gives you 2 rows which is not OP's desired output. You can check it yourself by using script provided by OP in question.

Comment: ok my bad. I thought that _get all data where the progress column contains the text tbd and the counter number is 1_ meant retrieving 2 rows only! thanks for him he posted a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Simply try:

```
select * from test where progress = 'tbd' and counter = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you:

```
select  *,
        row_number() over(partition by    Progress order by   Counter)
        rowID
into #tmp
from    Test

select  *
from    #tmp
where   ID in(
            select  ID
            from    #tmp
            where   Counter = 1
                    and Progress = 'tbd'
        )
order by    ID,
            rowID
```